# passing variables to an azure pipeline jobs template parameter

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to call a job template which I need to pass in a variable value generated by a script task with an example below. I want to have the functionality in a template but pass in different values depending which pipeline is being called so the values need to be dynamic.

I haven't been able to find a way to dynamically provide a value as a parameter similar to the example below as I understand that the expansion phase runs before the run phase etc

how can I achieve something like this?

```
- stage: StageA
  displayName: StageA
  jobs:
  - job: JobA
    steps:

    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: TaskA
      name: TaskA
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=animal;]cat"

  - template:  ../../templates/job-template.yaml
    parameters:
      applicationKeys: "${{ $[dependencies.JobA.outputs['TaskA.animal']] }}"
```

I have tried the code sample above with a few different options and it just doesnt seem to work

Comment: You can't do that. Parameters are resolved at template compilation time, which occurs *before* runtime variables are available.

Comment: How can you go about getting dynamic content passed into a templated job? data that you are generating during your pipeline execution?

Comment: As *parameters*? You don't. Look at the documentation that explains how template compilation works. It's not entirely intuitive. Everything related to template resolution and evaluation of expressions in `${{ }}` happens *very* early, where all of the YAML template files are being compiled into a single YAML document. A more concrete real-world example of what you're trying to accomplish might be useful to help you find a workable approach.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the isOutput param
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=animal;**isOutput**=true]cat"

Comment: thanks, that was a typo but the question is more about how to take data that you collect during your pipeline and pass it into a template job, say for example your job resets a list of applications. You might have a separate job which collects the list of applications which you then want to pass to your "resetapps" job for a specific environment